# Cannot activate Python virtual environment from within shell script (zsh)

Tags: python, shell, conda, zsh

I cannot activate a Python virtual environment from within a shell script (zsh).
I have tried the following:

```
#!/bin/zsh

conda create -n myenv python=3.10

conda activate myenv
```

It sends me the error message that I need to run `conda init`before `conda activate`, but that also does not work.

Has anybody an idea how to make this work?

The goal is to then be able to add `pip install <xyz>` commands into the script, so that overall:

(1) The virtual environment gets created

(2) The virtual environment gets activated

(3) The necessary packages get installed, i.e. `pip install notebook` etc.

All that from running this shell script, i.e. typing `zsh <shellscript>.sh` into the command line.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `activate` changes the state of your current shell -- so best case, inside a script, it can only change the state _of the shell that's running that script_, not the shell that _started_ the script. And to even be able to do _that_, you need to have `conda` defined _as a shell function_, not running as an external command -- and that's generally accomplished via dotfiles that set up your _interactive shell_ only.

Comment: just to check whether your conda installation is not broken, what happens when you use `bash` or `sh` instead of `zsh`? In script I usually don't use `conda activate` but `source path/to/conda/bin/activate myenv`

Comment: Which is all to say -- if you want this to work the same way it does if you type the same commands at your interactive shell, make it a function defined in your interactive shell's dotfiles, not a script at all. (You _could_ also make it a script intended to be sourced rather than executed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, I am new to all this. How do I do that?

Comment: Which "that"? Defining a shell function? Open up `~/.zshrc`, put `yourFunctionName() {` at the beginning of the function definition, the contents after (as subsequent lines), and `}` at the end; that'll define a command `yourFunctionName` you can run in interactive shells you subsequently start (or preexisting shells where you invoke `. ~/.zshrc` to force it to reread that file after already being started).

Comment: @NilsK Just to confirm, do you want the virtual environment to get activated for the calling shell? or only for the script?

Comment: @wjandrea I am a little confused with the terminology. I want to execute the script, so that when it is done, I am in the virtual environment that is set up. So I think that means that I want the virtual environment to get activated from the calling shell.

Comment: Part of `conda`'s initialization is to define a function named `conda` that wraps the command, so that `conda activate` (and `conda deactivate`) can update the current shell. All other subcommands are delegated to the actual `conda` command. (At least, that's what I understand from reading https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/dev-guide/deep-dives/activation.html.)The `conda` function, though, would not be available in your script, as functions are not inherited via the environment.

Comment: @NilsK Yes, that answers my question perfectly. Now you can do what Charles is saying :)

Comment: While the duplicate I linked mentions bash in the title, it's the same problem with both shells, and the same fix.